# How to get alarms from Bacnet using c#

Tags: c#, iot, bacnet

I am trying to access alarms from PLC which is running on Bacnet protocol. I am using Windows 10 IoT platform (running on RPI). I can read all Bacnet object "properties" such as event state, alarm etc but I need to get all alarms of all objects.

I know that GetAlarmSummary and GetEnrollmentSummary is deprecated and I should use GetEventInformation service but when I am browsing through objects I can find notification class objects but I do not know how they are connected with binary or analog objects.

I also know that Bacnet object like (binary, analog, multistateValue) has notification class number which indicates number of notification class connected to the object but I really don't know how they are reacting on each other and how is error message generated. I have noticed that objects with error has event state set to alarm but I do not know how they are cooperating with notification classes because when I try to browse notification class I only get type and priority but nothing about connected objects. Could anyone provide some sample of code that I could use or give me some points to finish this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether it helps or not; here's an example of the 'Get Alarm Summary' output:

```
    Items - Count = '5' -

            Idx = '0' -

                    Obj Id = '12582946' ('0xC00022')
                            - T  = 'BINARY_INPUT' ('3' / '0x3')
                            - I# = '34' ('0x22')
                            - N  = 'diagVasUnableToDriveMax|VAHU-01 VAS-2'
                    Alarm State = 'OFFNORMAL' ('2')
                    Ack Transitions = '111' ( 'To Off-Normal'; 'To Fault'; 'To Normal' )

            Idx = '1' -

                    Obj Id = '12582947' ('0xC00023')
                            - T  = 'BINARY_INPUT' ('3' / '0x3')
                            - I# = '35' ('0x23')
                            - N  = 'diagVasSourceTempFailure|VAHU-01 VAS-2'
                    Alarm State = 'OFFNORMAL' ('2')
                    Ack Transitions = '111' ( 'To Off-Normal'; 'To Fault'; 'To Normal' )

            Idx = '2' -

                    Obj Id = '12582948' ('0xC00024')
                            - T  = 'BINARY_INPUT' ('3' / '0x3')
                            - I# = '36' ('0x24')
                            - N  = 'diagVasSystemFailure|VAHU-01 VAS-2'
                    Alarm State = 'OFFNORMAL' ('2')
                    Ack Transitions = '111' ( 'To Off-Normal'; 'To Fault'; 'To Normal' )

            Idx = '3' -

                    Obj Id = '54525954' ('0x3400002')
                            - T  = 'MULTI_STATE_INPUT' ('13' / '0xD')
                            - I# = '2' ('0x2')
                            - N  = 'Communication Status|generic-2'
                    Alarm State = 'OFFNORMAL' ('2')
                    Ack Transitions = '111' ( 'To Off-Normal'; 'To Fault'; 'To Normal' )

            Idx = '4' -

                    Obj Id = '54526017' ('0x3400041')
                            - T  = 'MULTI_STATE_INPUT' ('13' / '0xD')
                            - I# = '65' ('0x41')
                            - N  = 'Communication Status|vav-28'
                    Alarm State = 'OFFNORMAL' ('2')
                    Ack Transitions = '111' ( 'To Off-Normal'; 'To Fault'; 'To Normal' )
```